# How to auto enter text or code?

Tags: database, excel, notepad++

Example Data:

```
0102030405060708091011121314151617181920
```

I want to make it like this: (if read 10 sel auto enter)

```
0102030405(enter)
0607080910(enter)
1112131415(enter)
1617181920(enter)
```

nt: horizontal (every 10 sel) to vertical

Comment: I think you may need to expand upon your question further (perhaps a little more context and an example of what you would expect to see happen)? Also, SO isn't intended to be a code writing service. See [ask]

Comment: Also check out the [tour] and [mcve].

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail. We are unable to understand anything from the question

Comment: You might want to investigate how " `regular expression` search and replace" would be useful to insert a linebreak every ten digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with:

[image]

running `MAIN()`:

```
Public Function frag(s As String, N As Long)
    Dim L As Long, K As Long
    L = Len(s)
    K = L / N
    ReDim ary(1 To K)

    For kk = 1 To K
        ary(kk) = Mid(s, N * kk - (N - 1), N)
    Next kk

    frag = ary
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    Dim st As String
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    With Range("A1")
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
    End With

    st = [A1]
    arr = frag(st, 10)

    [A1] = Join(arr, vbCrLf)

End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]